# Set a lineItem option from within a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I’m trying to set a specific lineItem option. Here is the gist of my attempt:

```
craft()->on('commerce_lineItems.onPopulateLineItem', function($event){

    $lineItem = $event->params['lineItem'];

    if (something == true) {
        $lineItem->options['optionKey'] = 'newValue';
    }

});
```

This returns an error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property…

What’s the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're doing this in a plugin and not the front end using an input for a reason?

I struggled with this recently and had luck using the following:

```
// Get the line item from the event
$item = $event->params['lineItem'];

// We get all the options from the post request
$options = craft()->request->getPost('options', []);

// Add the new value
$options['optionKey'] = 'newValue';

// Save the options to the line item
$item->options = $options;
```

If somebody can suggest an improvement to this I'd be grateful.